# SQL Query to show login count for each user in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I would like a query that displays the number of times each user has logged in to Wordpress. The result would be something like:

```
User  | Login_count
------------------
user1 | 2
------------------
user2 | 5
------------------
user3 | 0
```

etc..

Any ideas?

Comment: where is your structure and the statement that you tried ?

Comment: @Satya, I have not tried anything yet, I was just wondering if someone has written that query before. It just seems like something wp admins would be interested in.

Comment: if the table structure is something like username/logindate , I will write select username,count(*) from usertab group by  username  order by username

Comment: @maiorano84 thank you very much! I was not aware of that but it makes perfect sense. I will pay attention from now on.

Comment: @Satya yes that is the general approach, but you do not seem like you are familiar with Wordpress development. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'db_increment');
function db_increment($login)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I thought WP is already logging that information, but hey, this is a clever approach!

Answer (score 1):

Is better to use `update_user_meta` instead create separate SQL queries to achieve such a simple functionality.

Code (functions.php) for that will looks like:

```
function my_handle_login($username, $user) {
    $login_count = intval(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_count', true));

    $login_count++;
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_count', $login_count);

}
add_action('wp_login', 'my_handle_login', 10, 2);


function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['counter'] = 'Logins Count';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );


function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'counter' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'user_count', $user_id );
            break;
        default:
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```